# WeiboSDK NSConcreteMutableData wbsdk_base64EncodedString Error

Tags: swift, weibo

I got this error after using `WeiboSDK.registerApp` function:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteMutableData wbsdk_base64EncodedString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79f2bec0'

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

Set `Other Linker Flags` as `-all_load` in Project's Build Setting.

Comment: its not working ... when i was use it i am getting more than 9 error .